# Vuex v-model with an array

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I know to use v-model with vuex you use a computed property with a setter and getter, where the getter dispatches an action. How would this work when the property you want to bind with is an array? This is how the the code worked pre-Vuex so trying to convert it since newAds now is within Store.

```
<div v-for="ad in newAds" :key="ad.id">
        <div v-for="key in ad" :key="key.id">
           <input
                    type="text"
                    v-model="key.finalurl"
                    placeholder="www.books.com"
                    autofocus
                  >
         </div>
       </div>
```

Can I pass multiple parameters through a setter and then run that through to the mutation?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just try it and say what you got?

Comment: It didn't work when I tried and I couldn't find anything that showed passing multiple parameters to see if maybe just my syntax was wrong in some way, which led me to this post. I don't know what I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You can split `v-model` into the `@input` event handler and the `:value` property, and then handle multiple values, like this:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  :value="key.finalurl"
  @input="handleFinalURL"
  placeholder="www.books.com"
  autofocus
>
```

```js
methods: {
  handleFinalURL(value) {
    // do stuff here like
    callFunction(value, someOtherParam, extra)
  }
}
```

It's less handy but it will solve your problem.